# Resend data traffic from an Arduino

Tags: ethernet, tcpip

I have an Arduino with an Ethernet shield and I want to capture all Ethernet data traffic that connects to the Arduino via [as?] a router. This is because I want to use the Arduino like a *honeypot* and at the same time resend the Ethernet traffic to the Raspberry, *but only specific TCP traffic instead of UDP*.

In other words, I want to resend all of the traffic data from an Arduino to a Raspberry Pi, but I need to *only* resend all of the TCP traffic because the Raspberry reads and parses this. However, I only see examples of UDP traffic but nothing related to TCP. It doesn't matter what kind of port the Arduino listens on, I just need the data out of the other side, can you help me?

Comment: I am sorry, I am having a hard time understanding what you are asking here (I am guessing a language barrier). Can you clarify what it is you are trying to achieve? What traffic are you referring to - how does the arduino receive it? What form does it take?

Comment: Your question statement doesn't make a lot of sense, but I have to wonder at your design.  Given that a conventional Arduino has no network interface, and is terribly short on resources to deal with network traffic at all, it really makes little sense to connect a network to the Arduino, rather than directly to the pi.

Comment: Sorry, my english is not as well as I want, I am spanish user...well, I have an arduino with its ethernetshield, I want to capture all ethernet data traffic that connects to arduino since a router because I want to use the arduino like honeypot and at the same time resend the ethernet traffic to raspberry, but specific TCP traffic instead of UDP, I don't now If your are understand me, sorry.

Comment: I have tried to reword your question, although a few points remain unclear: when you say `since a router` ("desde un router"?) do you mean that you have the Pi and the Arduino both connected to a router? Or are you using the Arduino as a router/filter to filter the traffic and only resending TCP traffic on to the Pi? To do the latter, you would need two Ethernet shields, one for the incoming UDP and TCP packets and one for the outgoing TCP packets that will go to the Pi. You would also need to use a hub, and not a switch or router as otherwise the Arduino will only see traffic intended for it.

Comment: Also, can you post your sketch that you are using with the Arduino, to filter the packets, and also a network diagram to clarify how you have the Pi and the Arduino (and the router (if there is one) and the rest of the network) connected? As it stands your question is rather unclear and is likely to be closed, unless your provide clearer information and the sketch and the network diagram to illustrate what you actually mean.